# Divide numbers from prompt in new function

Tags: javascript, prompt, calculation

I have a program written that calculates bank notes that you have to pay (2,5,10,20,...) from a number you type into the prompt.

I would like to take it further to the next step - I want to take that number from the prompt that was inserted on the first step and divide it by number user types into a new prompt to calculate the average cost of one item.

How can I do that?

This is the code that I have written for the first part.

```js
var stevilo = prompt("Vnesi znesek:");

var bankovec = [500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1];
var stevilo_bankovcev = 0;
var izpisi = "";
for (i = 0; i < bankovec.length; i++) {
  var y = stevilo / bankovec[i];
  if (y >= 1) {
    var razlika = Math.floor(y) * bankovec[i];
    stevilo = stevilo - razlika;
    stevilo_bankovcev = Math.floor(y) + stevilo_bankovcev;
    izpisi = izpisi + Math.floor(y) + "x" + bankovec[i] + ",";
    console.log(izpisi);
  }
}
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("gremo").innerHTML = "Za plačilo je potrebno " + izpisi;
}
```

```html
<span id="gremo"></span>
```

Comment: define "user inserts"

Comment: @jasper "types in a new prompt"

Comment: All that is mentioned here is about determining bank notes from a given amount. I'm not sure what "item" and "cost" mean here. You also mentioned "average", which seems to indicate multiple items, or maybe multiple user entries. Please elaborate.

Comment: In the first part user types in 896, and the program gives the answer: "You have to pay 1x500$,1x200$,1x100$,1x50$,2x20$,1x5$,1x1$", now I want the program to open a new prompt and ask: How many products you bought?...and the user types lets say 5, and the program takes the number 896 and divides it by 5 and gives the answer of the average cost for one item. Did I explain this good enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether I understand the question correctly, but if the only thing you wanted to add to your program was another variable which user inputs, and then do a division with that variable, this would do the trick (although Im not entirely sure what the usage of this would be):

```js
var stevilo = prompt("Vnesi znesek:");
var division = prompt("Dividing by this number:");

var bankovec = [500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1];
var stevilo_bankovcev = 0;
var total = stevilo/division;
var izpisi = "";
for (i = 0; i < bankovec.length; i++) {
  var y = stevilo / bankovec[i];
  if (y >= 1) {
    var razlika = Math.floor(y) * bankovec[i];
    stevilo = stevilo - razlika;
    stevilo_bankovcev = Math.floor(y) + stevilo_bankovcev;
    izpisi = izpisi + Math.floor(y) + "x" + bankovec[i] + ",";
    console.log(izpisi);
  }
}
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("gremo").innerHTML = "Za plačilo je potrebno " + izpisi + " whereas the division's result is: " + total;
}
```

```html
<span id="gremo"></span>
```

Basically just call another prompt, save it into another variable and then divide with it.

Regards,
B

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I wanted! Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep some local state, try this out:

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/jasperdg/pen/mdVPKON?editors=1111)

```
  <span id="gremo"></span>
  <span id="avg"></span>
  <button id="add">add item</button>
```

```
var pastItemPrices = [];

function calcBills() {
    var stevilo = prompt("Vnesi znesek:");
    pastItemPrices.push(parseInt(stevilo));
    var bankovec = [500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1];
    var stevilo_bankovcev = 0;
    var izpisi = "";
    for (i = 0; i < bankovec.length; i++) {
        var y = stevilo / bankovec[i]; 
        if (y >= 1) {
        var razlika = Math.floor(y) * bankovec[i];
            stevilo = stevilo - razlika;
            stevilo_bankovcev = Math.floor(y) + stevilo_bankovcev;
            izpisi = izpisi + Math.floor(y) + "x" + bankovec[i] + ",";
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("gremo").innerHTML = "Za plačilo je potrebno " + izpisi;
    document.getElementById("avg").innerHTML = "Average price: " + pastItemPrices.reduce((total, price) => total + price) / pastItemPrices.length
}

window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", calcBills);
    calcBills();
}
```

Comment: This works the way I want it to work. But If I type the first number 100, and then divide with 2, it gives me the answer 51? Why does it do that and do you have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
function znesek() {
  var stevilo = prompt("Vnesi znesek:");
  const stevilo1 = stevilo; // take a copy
  var bankovec = [500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1];
  var stevilo_bankovcev = 0;
  var izpisi = "";
  for (i = 0; i < bankovec.length; i++) {
    var y = stevilo / bankovec[i];
    if (y >= 1) {
      var razlika = Math.floor(y) * bankovec[i];
      stevilo = stevilo - razlika;
      stevilo_bankovcev = Math.floor(y) + stevilo_bankovcev;
      izpisi = izpisi + Math.floor(y) + "x" + bankovec[i] + ",";
//      console.log(izpisi);
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("gremo").innerHTML = "Za plačilo je potrebno " + izpisi;
  setTimeout(function() { drugZnesek(stevilo1) } ,10); // allow DOM update
}
function drugZnesek(stevilo1) {
  var drugStevilo =  prompt("Vnesi drug znesek")
  if (stevilo1 && isNaN(stevilo1) || isNaN(drugStevilo)) {
    document.getElementById("gremo").innerHTML = "Žal ne številk";
    return;
  }
  else {
    console.log(stevilo1,drugStevilo,stevilo1/drugStevilo)
    document.getElementById("gremo").innerHTML += "<br/>"+(stevilo1/drugStevilo).toFixed(2)
  }
}  
window.addEventListener("load", znesek)
```

```html
<span id="gremo"></span>
```

Comment: Are you from Slovenia? I see you have written the code in the same language as I did in my question! I tried this but after typing the other number the calculation is always 0.

Comment: I just used google translate to find slovenian words for you. Just part of the service ;)
Since I do not know what your calculation is supposed to do, I just tried something. See update

Comment: Yeah, I did not see you subtracted from stevilo  - now I take a copy